# How do I zoom out in Internet Explorer via Parallels?

Tags: macos, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, parallels

I am using Parallels to test IE (IE11 for starters).

My IE browser is at a huge resolution.  How can I 'zoom out'?

If I try and use the command +/- I get the magnifier application.  Not what I want.

If I change the screen resolution thw indow and background change.  But not the IE11 window.

There is no right-click zoom out when on IE11 (in Windows 8.1)

[image]

If I shrink down my parallels IE window so that text is similar to a firefox window I have to shrink it down to this (IE11 is the box on the top right):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use IE's 'zoom' feature which available within IE under settings which is the small icon with a cog as shown here on the right:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A very useful way to zoom in most any program and any browser is to hold ***CTRL + MOUSEWHEEL+/-*** Which will zoom in or out depending on the direction which you scroll the *Mousewheel*.

This way is the most efficient and will work in a large variety of programs and *IDE*'s.